# Discord Отслеживание реакции

Tags: python, discord

Задача:
1) отсчитывать, кто поставил игроку реакцию на его сообщение
2) если это был модератор, то выдавать игроку определённую роль
Как это сделать?
P.s. Заранее спасибо:)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы код ниже заработал, в текстовом канале должны быть соответствующие роли `test_role` и `new_role` (это имена ролей - могут быть любые на ваше усмотрение). У пользователя, который ставит реакцию, должна быть роль, в которой есть права на выдачу ролей. Пример ролей в моем текстовом канале:

[image: Роли на текстовом канале]

Пример реализации события добавление любой реакции к сообщению пользователя (каждая строка прокомментирована для удобства понимания, что происходит в процессе работы):

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
  # Получение реакции на сообщение
  message_id = payload.message_id # ID сообщения
  channel_id = payload.channel_id # ID канала
  channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id) # Получаем канал
  message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id) # Получаем сообщение
  author = message.author # Автор сообщения
  user_id = payload.user_id # ID пользователя, который добавил реакцию
  user = channel.guild.get_member(user_id) # Пользователь, который добавил реакцию
  # Ищем роль с названием new_role (выводом будет список из 1 элемента)
  add_role = [role for role in channel.changed_roles if role.name == 'new_role']
  for role in user.roles: # Проходим по списку ролей пользователя
    if role.name == 'test_role': # Если у пользователя есть роль 'test_role'
      await user.add_roles(add_role[0]) # Добавляем роль пользователю
```